# In a Rails log file, what does "Processing by ProductsController#index as */*" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails log file, I see lots of

```
Started GET "/" for 63.148.78.244 at Fri Sep 24 19:03:39 +0000 2010
  Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
```

I understand this means Rails is serving up an HTML page.  However, what does this mean?

```
Started GET "/" for 63.148.78.244 at Fri Sep 24 18:05:51 +0000 2010
  Processing by ProductsController#index as */*
Completed   in 0ms
```

Why the `*/*`?

Comment: I've noticed that typically web crawlers like Googlebot will cause Rails to serve a */* response (for the reasons outlined in the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the HTTP_ACCEPT header that is sent by the browser. The common scenario is that the browser sends list of all MIME types that can process and server returns the result in one of them - typically HTML.

But in some cases it's not this way. For example if you use *wget* without any other parameters.

Try

```
wget http://yourserver
```

and you will see in your log file * / * which means that the "browser" accepts anything you will send back (it's quite obvious that wget can accept anything as it is just storing it into the file).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the use of the word `browser`. In the example of wget - do you mean that it acts as a browser/user agent?

Comment: Yes, you are right - the use of word `browser` is a bit confusing and I would better use `http client` (that would cover browser, wget, curl, googelbot, xhr, etc.)