# index.js.haml is not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am using inherited_resources and in my controller I specified `respond_to :js, :only => [:index]`.

But when I trigger an oncange event for dropdown a ajax url that hits the controller index method with appropriate queries.

I am trying to refresh the `div` using `index.js.haml`. But it was not loading.

In my rails log

I am getting `Processing by MessagesController#index as */*`

Why I didn't get this with `'js'` format instead of `*/*`.
Where I am doing wrong? How to get this to work?

Comment: add javascript code where you make ajax call.

Comment: Use index.js.html

not index.js.haml

Answer (score 0):

" */ * "means that the "browser" accepts anything you will send back , It basically depends on HTTP_ACCEPT send by browsers.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793974/1970061 for more details.

Your div is not refreshing because your JavaScript in response Text is not executing. Use Jquery eval() function to Run javascript of response text